# Block jquery function while something is sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have a menu with 6 options, each one of them is supposed to show a div elsewhere with some text. I added jQuery function to this menu, when I click any option, the correct div slides down and any other div slides up again.

The problem is, if someone clicks very fast on different items, more than one div open at the same time. How can I control this, like disabling the function while the div is loading/unloading?

It is simple HTML, no PHP page.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `animate()` or are using the `queue()` you can use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) to end animations.

Without seeing your code or HTML that's about as much help as I can offer.

A potential example:

```
<ul class="my-collapsible-content">
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some other text</li>
  <li>Some more text</li>
</ul>


$('.my-collapsible-content').on('click', '>li', function(){
    $(this).siblings().stop(true, true); //stops animation and jumps to 'final' state immediately
    $(this).animate(.....);
})
```

Comment: I'm actually using only "slideDown" and "slideUp" functions.

Comment: those are just convenience functions to `animate`. Still applies

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/ to see if something is being animated, and if so, return;

Example:

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
    if ($(".slider:animated")) return;
    //DO YOUR ANIMATION CODE
});
```

You can also try adding a global variable, like "var animating". set it to true when you start the animation. then set it back to false when the animation completes.

Then in your click function(s) only allow a click if(animating == false)

```
var animating;

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    if(!animating){
        animating = true;
        $('#book').animate({
            opacity: 0.25,
            left: '+=50',
            height: 'toggle'
        }, 5000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Kind of work, but also if I click too fast it freezes. I added "else { sliding = false; }" to the end, seems not neat, but works.

Comment: which solution did you use? The :animated or the variable method? I think the :animated jquery built-in option is probably the best approach